# Implementing adaptive timestepping in CUDA

Tags: cuda, adaptive-timestepping

I want to implement a CUDA solver for the 2D shallow water equations using adaptive timestepping with a Courant number fixed by the user.  The algorithm pseudocode looks something like this:

```cpp
while (t < end_time)
{
  evolve_flow_variables();
  dt = global_minimum_dt_over_all_elements_in_mesh();
  t += dt;
}
```

I've seen example CUDA code with fixed timestepping (e.g. [lecture 2](https://www.bu.edu/pasi/materials/post-pasi-training/post-pasi-training-week-1/) slides and code from Boston University) that makes multiple CUDA kernel calls from the time loops on the CPU, and synchronises only at the end:

```cpp
const dt;
while (t < end_time)
{
  evolve_flow_variables<<<grid_size, block_size>>>();
  t += dt;
}
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

But I don't think this is feasible with adaptive timestepping.  Calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after every timestep seems like a bad idea and, from my own measurements with Boston University's example code, the code could be up to twice as slow.

I'm aware of in-kernel [grid synchronisation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#grid-synchronization-cg) introduced in CUDA 9 that could allow me to put the entire time loop inside the kernel, but I'd rather be able to support slightly older devices.

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful but there was a paper published by colleagues that uses adaptivity in both space and time on GPUs that may be of interest:  https://doi.org/10.1029/2019MS001635.  Note that there's also an arXiv version as well along with code on github.

Comment: @KyleMandli I hadn't seen that paper, it has an excellent overview of how to implement a Godunov-type structured mesh solver in CUDA which will be very helpful.